# Magento 2 How to override sales.order.items.renderers block in sales_order_view page?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, override-block

I am trying to override `sales_order_view.xml` file `sales.order.items.renderers` block, I have followed below mentioned code but not worked:

overriding `sales_order_view.xml` in custom module :

**Method 1 :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="order_items">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.order.items.renderers" as="renderer.list" template="Vendor_Namespace::order/items/renderer/default.phtml"/>
            </referenceBlock>

        </body>
    </page>
```

**Method 2 :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers">
               <arguments>
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Namespace::order/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

**Method 3 :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                   <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Namespace::order/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
               </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

and I created `order/items.renderer/default.phtml` file in custom module, but it is not overriding.

Any help will appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers.default">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Namespace::order/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please use reference block name `sales.order.items.renderers.default`

Hope this will help you!

Comment: worked, thankyou :)

Comment: thankyou @Kishan :)

Comment: Always welcome :)

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, in which file we have to add this code and mention file path please..

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Namespace::order/items/renderer/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: please check my question, I already tried this one

Comment: Yes, but you do not write `<referenceBlock name="sales.order.items.renderers">`. Please check it in your question.

Comment: sorry writing mistake here, question updated now.